# pwa workbox not finding response in cache

Tags: vaadin, workbox, progressive-web-apps

I have configured the following workbox route to cache all articles taken from the news service newsapi.org.  I can see that articles are being stored in the cache, however when I go offline mode in chrome, then try to access the cached url, workbox tells me that no response is found in the cache (even though I can see it there).  What am I missing here? 
Original code based on [Vaadin Progressive Web App tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gcx-3qi7t7c)

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  // Cache news articles
  new RegExp('^https?:\/\/newsapi.org/(.*)'), args => {
  return workbox.strategies.networkFirst({
    cacheName: 'news-cache',
    plugins: [
      new workbox.expiration.Plugin({
        maxEntries: 20,
        maxAgeSeconds: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60,
      })
    ],
  }).handle(args).then(response => {
    if (!response) {
      return caches.match('./fallback.json');
    }
    return response;
  });
});
```

[image: Response not found in cache]

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? Can you put a breakpoint in the response block and see if it gets there?

Comment: Try removing the `workbox.expiration.Plugin` plugin. I don't know why but it seems to be causing issues on your site.

Comment: Thanks, I removed the expiration plugin and this fixed the problem.  Could you explain how you figured this out.  Is this a bug with Workbox?

Comment: If you're using Workbox 3.0, then you might be running into an issue that was fixed in Workbox 3.1: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/pull/1422 If you're using the latest Workbox and still have the issue, please open a bug on the Workbox issue tracker and let us know.